# Echo next row from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

To select the previous row in MySQL I use the following script, which works perfect:

```
<?php
$previous = $row['id'] - 1;
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = $previous");
while($row =$stmt->fetch()){echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a>';}
?>
```

In order to select the **next** row I want to use this script:

```
<?php
$next = $row['id'] + 1;
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = $next");
while($row =$stmt->fetch()){echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a>';}
?>
```

This fetch the first record of the database and not the next row.

Comment: this is a bad idea: you should not put meaning into the value of an ID column. Not even (or maybe cerntrainly not) to deterimen the order of rows. And what if at some day you decide to delete row 4? If you still choose to use the ID column: WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1

Comment: @IvoP, your comment seems to imply that the id should not be used to determine the order of the rows and yet you then go on to say use `id > 3 ORDER BY id`.  So does that mean that it can be used to determine the order or not?

Comment: I first say you should not do so. But if you do choose to use ID for that purpose then.... Compare it to the SocialSecurityNo. In many countries there is no link between one's age and this "id". Still one could order a list of people by this number. Or by one's postal code. But try to do no more with an ID column then IDentify a row. As you could fi. never place a "forgotten" record between 2 others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the previous row values, you write the data to `$row`, so when trying to fetch the next row, the value of `$row['id']` is in fact the previous row id.

So store the value...

```
$currentID = $row['id'];
$previous = $currentID - 1;

// Other code
$next = $currentID + 1;
```

Comment: the previous should be the record with the greatest value of ID that is less than the current. That way you are still able to delete records in your database

Comment: Thanks everybody for your greatful help! Nigels' answer did the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

that is not the way you use mysql queries, you only want to run one query and then you loop on your results

either someting like

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id");
while($row =$stmt->fetch()){
  echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id");
$results = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ( $results as $key => $row ) {
  echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to add '1' in id and get the data. Its a bad idea. Accordingly if you want a next record then you should check a greater then, else use a lesser then for previous record. Simply...

```
$id=$row['id'];
```

next:

```
select * from <yout_table> where id = (select min(id) from <yout_table> where id > '$id')
```

previous:

```
select * from <yout_table> where id = (select max(id) from <yout_table> where id < '$id')
```

Its is work definitely....